# Function and class to control a TextBox in word (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following problem:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   Control (this)                <<<<----- this is Empty
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
   Control (this)                <<<<----- this is Empty
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
   Control (this)                <<<<----- this is Empty
End Sub

Public Sub Control(asdf As MSForms.TextBox)
    asdf.Font.Size = 11
    asdf.Font.Bold = True    
End Sub
```

The compiler says that 'this' is empty. What should I put there to recognize the TextBox?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you end up having a lot of textboxes, it may be easier to customize the event handler in a custom class.

In a standard module, put a globally scoped collection variable

```
Public gcolTextboxes As Collection
```

Create a custom class module called CTbxEvents

```
Private WithEvents mtb As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Get tb() As MSForms.TextBox
    Set tb = mtb
End Property

Public Property Set tb(otb As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set mtb = otb
End Property

Private Sub mtb_Change()

    tb.Font.Size = 11
    tb.Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Finally, in ThisDocument, load up all the textboxes when the document opens.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    Dim f As Field
    Dim clsTbxEvents As CTbxEvents

    'Globally scoped collection to hold the classes
    Set gcolTextboxes = New Collection

    'Loop throught the fields
    For Each f In Me.Fields
        'Only fields that are activex controls
        If f.Type = wdFieldOCX Then
            'only activex controsl that are textboxes
            If TypeOf f.OLEFormat.Object Is MSForms.TextBox Then
                'create a new class, add the textbox, add to collection
                Set clsTbxEvents = New CTbxEvents
                Set clsTbxEvents.tb = f.OLEFormat.Object
                gcolTextboxes.Add clsTbxEvents
            End If
        End If
    Next f

End Sub
```

Now any textbox you add will use the same event handler and you don't keep having to call a separate sub. If you truly only have three textboxes, it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

When you use parentheses in your code you're *evaluating* `Me.TextBox1`, which ends up passing a String to Control. If you drop the parens it will work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   Control Me.TextBox1 'without the parens         
End Sub
```

Typically you don't use `()` when calling a Sub, unless you're using `Call`

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is specific to C++/C#/Java, the corresponding keyword for VB/VB.NET is `Me`

Comment: Thx for the answer. I changed but still not working. What should I put there to the class Control recognize each TextBox(1,2,3)?

Comment: If I call 'ControlarTextBox (TextBox1)' it does not work as well. I'm lost.

Comment: When you use `Control(TextBox1)` (assuming you have a textbox with that name) does it work? if not, do you get an error or the method is not being called?